# Bash For-Loop on Directories

Tags: bash, loops, shell, directory

Quick Background:

```
$ ls src
file1  file2  dir1  dir2  dir3
```

Script:

```
#!/bin/bash

for i in src/* ; do
  if [ -d "$i" ]; then
    echo "$i"
  fi
done
```

Output:

```
src/dir1
src/dir2
src/dir3
```

However, I want it to read:

```
dir1
dir2
dir3
```

Now I realize I could sed/awk the output to remove "src/" however I am curious to know if there is a better way of going about this. Perhaps using a find + while-loop instead.

Answer (score 26, accepted):

Do this instead for the `echo` line:

```
 echo $(basename "$i")
```

Comment: I see you've updated your post to read *basename* instead of *dirname*
ding,ding,ding CORRECT !!! :D
Thanks, I will accept your answer

Comment: Learnt this nugget just 2 days ago from an O'Rielly book. Could have saved me hours of sed tomfoolery if I'd know it years ago.

Comment: This only solves printing, but the for loop is still running over the files. The question title wants a for loop on directories only. For users looking for that: https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/86724/46717

Answer (score 17):

No need for forking an external process:

```
echo "${i##*/}"
```

It uses the “remove the longest matching prefix” [parameter expansion](http://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/html_node/Shell-Parameter-Expansion.html). 
The `*/` is the pattern, so it will delete everything from the beginning of the string up to and including the last slash. If there is no slash in the value of `$i`, then it is the same as `"$i"`.

This particular parameter expansion is [specified in POSIX](http://www.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/009695399/utilities/xcu_chap02.html#tag_02_06_02) and is part of the legacy of the original Bourne shell. It is supported in all Bourne-like shells (*sh*, *ash*, *dash*, *ksh*, *bash*, *zsh*, etc.). Many of the feature-rich shells (e.g. *ksh*, *bash*, and *zsh*) have other expansions that can handle even more without involving external processes.

Answer (score 8):

If you do a `cd` at the start of the script, it should be reverted when the script exits.

```
#!/bin/bash

cd src
for i in * ; do
  if [ -d "$i" ]; then
    echo "$i"
  fi
done
```

Comment: it should… but if you use the `.` or `source` command to invoke the script, it won't. Rather use `pushd` and `popd`.

Answer (score 5):

Use `basename` as:

```
if [ -d "$i" ]; then
    basename "$i"
fi
```