# How can I loop through a list of files, from directories specified in a variable?

Tags: bash

I am trying to loop through the files in some directories, and performa an action on each file.

The list of directories is specified by a list of strings, stored as an environment variable

LIST_OF_DIRECTORIES=dir1 dir2 dir3

```
for dir in $LIST_OF_DIRECTORIES; do
  for file in $dir/* ; do
      echo $file
  done
done
```

This results in nothing. I'm expecting all of the files within that directory to be echoed.

I am basing my logic off of [Bash For-Loop on Directories](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4011668/bash-for-loop-on-directories), and trying to make this work for my use case.

Comment: Is `LIST_OF_DIRECTORIES` actually set to anything? If you declared it exactly like you stated in the question then I expect it's empty and you have an error like `dir2: command not found` somewhere in your script. Recommend confirming variable contents by adding `set -x`.

Comment: Also the more standard practice to store a list of strings is an array rather than a string.

Comment: Note that `LIST_OF_DIRECTORIES="dir1 dir2 dir3"` **doesn't actually create a list at all**; it creates a single string. Splitting that string into a list with an unquoted expansion as `for dir in $LIST_OF_DIRECTORIES` does is bad practice: it doesn't work with all possible directory names (remember, filenames can have spaces!), and its behavior can change depending on the current working directory the code is run in.

Comment: (Also, all-caps variable names are in a space used for variables that reflect or modify the behavior of OS-vendor-provided tools; for your own scripts you should use variable names with at least one lower-case character when you aren't trying to intentionally interact with an OS-defined variable; see https://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/basedefs/V1_chap08.html, keeping in mind that environment variables and shell variables share a single namespace)

Comment: A better-practice alternative would be more like `dirs=( dir1 dir2 dir3 )` and then later `for dir in "${dirs[@]}"; do ...`

Comment: If list of directories are all subdirectories within any set of directories, you can simply use `find` to identify them, and feed a `while` loop looping over each. (or simply use `find` to locate all files within a given set of directories).

Comment: Use [Shellcheck](https://www.shellcheck.net/) to find problems in your code.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have to place strings with spaces around quotes otherwise each "word" will be interpreted separately.  In your example, `LIST_OF_DIRECTORIES=dir1` is executed (`dir1` is indeed assigned `LIST_OF_DIRECTORIES`), but because it precedes a now interpreted simple command (`dir2 dir3`), it only lives temporarily for that command.

You should do either of these instead:

```
LIST_OF_DIRECTORIES="dir1 dir2 dir3"
LIST_OF_DIRECTORIES='dir1 dir2 dir3'
```

From [Simple Command Expansion](https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/html_node/Simple-Command-Expansion.html):

> If no command name results, the variable assignments affect the
> current shell environment. In the case of such a command (one that
> consists only of assignment statements and redirections), assignment
> statements are performed before redirections. Otherwise, the variables
> are added to the environment of the executed command and do not affect
> the current shell environment. If any of the assignments attempts to
> assign a value to a readonly variable, an error occurs, and the
> command exits with a non-zero status.

Also as a suggestion, use arrays for storing multiple entries instead and don't use word splitting unless your script doesn't use filename expansion and `noglob` is enabled with `set -f` or `shopt -so noglob`.

```
LIST_OF_DIRECTORIES=(dir1 dir2 dir3)

for dir in "${LIST_OF_DIRECTORIES[@]}"; do
```

Other References:

- [Quoting](https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/html_node/Quoting.html)
- [Arrays](https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/html_node/Arrays.html)
- [Filename Expansion](https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/html_node/Filename-Expansion.html)
- [Word Splitting](https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/html_node/Word-Splitting.html)

Comment: An array would be best if this is indeed bash as OP has it tagged. `LIST_OF_DIRECTORIES=( "dir1" "dir2" "dir3" )`

Comment: @tjm3772 Right, added as suggestion.

Answer (score -1):

This will work fine for you as.

```
LIST_OF_DIRECTORIES="dir1 dir2 dir3"
for dir in $LIST_OF_DIRECTORIES;
#add all the files to the files variable
do        files=`ls $dir`;
for file in $files;
#Take action on your file here, I am just doing ls for my file here. 
do echo `ls $dir/$file`;
done;
done
```

Comment: Don't use `for i in $(ls anything)`, see [Bash Pitfalls **#1**](http://mywiki.wooledge.org/BashPitfalls#for_i_in_.24.28ls_.2A.mp3.29) -- there is a reason that's `#1`. Have a look why and then bookmark [**Bash Pitfalls**](http://mywiki.wooledge.org/BashPitfalls), [**Bash FAQ**](http://mywiki.wooledge.org/BashFAQ) and [**Bash Guide**](http://mywiki.wooledge.org/BashGuide)

Comment: Use [Shellcheck](https://www.shellcheck.net/) to find problems in your code.